# How to receive php array in R?

Tags: php, r

I want to receive php array in R and send response to php,I complete the php code,but i don't know "R".

In this case,first i read the csv using php,then store it into php array,
then exec the **R script** in php,i am using **Ubuntu** operating system,so i am not include the full path.

I read a link in stack overflow for get **variables** from php in **R**.but i can't do it for **php array**.

This my php code

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['csv_size']))
 {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $csv_length = $_POST['csv_size'];
    $post_val = $_POST['asa'];
    $csvname = $_POST['csv_name'];
    $data = array();
    $val_data = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$csv_length;$i++)
    {
        array_push($data,$i);   
    }
    $result=array_intersect($data,$post_val);
    $data_final = array();
    $file = fopen($csvname,"r");
    $picked  = array(0,2);
    $N = array();
    if(($handle = fopen($csvname, "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
          $numCols = count($data);
          $row     = array();
          for($c=0; $c < $numCols; $c++)
            if(in_array($c, $post_val))
                $row[] = $data[$c];
          $N[] = $row;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } 
    exec("Rscript exec_r.R $N",$opt_age_json1); // <--- Running R script
    $str = $opt_age_json1[0];
    $myobj = json_decode($str);
    echo $myobj->first_name;
}
```

?>

**R CODE**

```
exec_r.R (R file)

This below code taken from stack overflow for send variables from php to R, i include here for your reference

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
tmp <- strsplit(args, " ")
N <- args[1]
N<-as.numeric(N)
m<-N+10
output <- list(first_name=m)
library(rjson)
cat(toJSON(output))

the above example Work's in my local machine
```

-- Thanks in advance

Comment: *the above example Work's in my local machine*...then what is the problem? Also, do note R can read in csv files.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment,The above code is for send receive **variables**,i need to  send the **array** to R. I want to send php '$N' **array**  to R.

Comment: Did you check your PHP versions in the local machine vs the server?

Comment: Thanks Tal for coming here,Yeah, I check the version. In php code finally i store the csv values in '$N' array,then i send the '$N' array to **R** . But i can't receive the array and process the array from **R** to **PHP** .

Comment: Forgive me in insisting but R can read in csv files, and PHP can convert arrays to json. Is there a reason you need to interface between two languages?

Comment: Yes I want to connect both for a client task,If you know anything please share with me.